# How to display errors from array response after validation from laravel to vue.js (based on the index)

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, response

I'm trying to display the errors in the correct order (based on the index) from the response I have in laravel api.

**Errors displayed on vue using** `{{ errors }}` **:**

`{ "options.cart.0.request": [ "options.cart.0.request es is invalid." ], "options.cart.3.request": [ "options.cart.3.request is invalid." ] }`

Function that calls the api - Response Status code that I get is 422  :

```
        async doOrder () {
            axios.post('api/order', this.user).then( response => {
                this.$store.dispatch('auth/updateUser', { user : response.data })
            }).catch(error => {
                if (error.response.status === 404) {
                    this.$router.push('/404');
                }
                if (error.response.status === 422 ) {
                    this.errors = error.response.data.errors
                }
            });
```

**Laravel Validation :**

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $this->validate( $request, [
            'options.cart' => 'required|array',
            'options.cart.*.code' => 'required|exists:products,code',
            'options.cart.*.request' => 'required|in:1,2',
        ]);

        return $request; //Testing

    }
```

**Vue v-for :**

```
        <section id="request" v-if="user.options.cart.length > 0">
            <div class="card-body" v-for="(object , index) in user.options.cart" :key="object.product_id">
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-8 text-md-right form-group" style="padding-top: 5px">
                    <select class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" :class="errors ? 'is-invalid' : ''" name="request" required v-model="object.request">
                        <option value="1" :selected="object.request == 1 ">Amostras</option>
                        <option value="2" :selected="object.request == 2 ">Informações / Cotação</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="errors.errors">Example invalid custom select feedback</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: In your use-case, what do you mean by "correct order"?

Comment: Its an array of options. Show the results for each element of the array / object.I want to put the error below the object that has errors.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this question? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to use validator facades like this

```
    $validator = \Validator::make(request()->all(), [
        'options.cart' => 'required|array',
        'options.cart.*.code' => 'required|exists:products,code',
        'options.cart.*.request' => 'required|in:1,2',
    ]);

if($validator->fails()){
    return response()->json(['status' => false, 'data' => $validator->errors()]);
}
```

Comment: I got the same result: ``{"status":false,"error":{"options.cart.0.request":["options.cart.0.request is invalid."]}}``

Answer (score 0):

please follow along,

in your controller

---

```
 $request->validate([
        'ClinicName' => 'required|string|min:200',
        'Branches.*.BranchName'=>'required|string|min:200'
    ]);
```

in your vue3 file, to access the errors which will have keys such as,
'Branches.0.BranchName'
then you can access the above error with for loop  similar to this

---

```
<p v-if="form.errors['Branches.' + counter + '.BranchName']"
   class="mt-2 text-sm text-red-600 dark:text-red-500">
              {{ form.errors["Branches." + counter + ".BranchName"] }}
 </p>
```

here the counter can be any counter starting from 0.